# jQuery UI drop event fired without leaving mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

in the below fiddle when i drag an element from the sortable to the droppable area and then i drag it over the sortable area without dropping it, if i drag it over the droppable area it gets a drop event even if you do not release the mouse click!
in result i get the element duplicated :-)
is this a reasonable behavior or a bug?

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  // https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8135 --> http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/gtKtE/277/
  start: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;'); },
});
  
$('.dropzone').droppable({
  accept: '.sortable .item',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  // This is called multiple times.
    // when i drop an item from the sortable to drop zone
    // and then drag this dropped item out of the dropzone and in again,
    // this is fired and item gets dupliate :-)
    console.log('droppable.drop!');
    ui.draggable.remove();
    var dropedItem = ui.draggable.clone();
    dropedItem.appendTo($(this));
    dropedItem.draggable({
      connectToSortable: '.sortable',
    });
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('droppable.over');
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('droppable.out');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.sortable {
 font-size: 0px;
 height: auto;
 background-color: red;
 overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
/*    padding: 4px;*/
}

.item {
 font-size: 13px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropzone {
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 0px;
 background-color: blue;
 min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 
 <div class="sortable">
  <div class="item">Item #1</div>
  <div class="item">Item #2</div>
  <div class="item">Item #3</div>
  <div class="item">Item #4</div>
  <div class="item">Item #5</div>
  <div class="item">Item #6</div>
  <div class="item">Item #7</div>
  <div class="item">Item #8</div>
  <div class="item">Item #9</div>
  <div class="item">Item #10</div>
 </div>

 <div class="dropzone">

 </div>

</div>
```

jQuery UI 1.12.1
jQuery 3.3.1
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/paranic/xpvt214o/362238/

Comment: Based on the steps you provided, I cannot replicate the issue. Please provide clearer steps on how to replicate the issue.

Comment: 1. drag an element to the blue dropzone
2. now take this element and drag it up and down, passing over the sortable, without leaving mouse click.

Comment: I have tested it with the new instructions you provided and am not able to replicate the issue as you described it. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/5/ 1) Drag element to drop 2) drop item 3) drag item toward sortable, do not release 4) drag back and forth without releasing.

Comment: Ok, I had to be more aggressive. I was able to replicate the issue by dragging outside of the viewport such that the mouse left the document. At this time, drop was triggered.

Comment: You can fix this by containment. Wrap your whole space with a container so that users cannot drag the item outside of sortable or droppable.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I was able to replicate the issue. When dragging out of the `document` the element is no longer "attached" the mousedown event in a sense. `drop` is triggered.

Work around, use `containment` option.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/8/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.sortable').sortable({
    containment: ".container",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;');
    },
  });

  $('.dropzone').droppable({
    accept: '.sortable .item',
    containment: ".container",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('droppable.drop!');
      ui.draggable.remove();
      var dropedItem = ui.draggable.clone();
      dropedItem.appendTo($(this));
      dropedItem.draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.sortable',
      });
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('droppable.over');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('droppable.out');
    }
  });
});
```

Now you cannot "lose" your item and drop is not triggered.

Comment: still doesn't work  
even if i sent containment on the cloned draggable item  
what browser are you using? i tested chrome and firefox.

Comment: @paranic was testing in FF 60.0.2 on Linux, 32-bit.

Comment: @paranic I can too get it to replicate when I really yank the mouse out of the frame. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/13/ and  https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/13/show/ Now, if you notice in the 2nd link, it only happens across the top of the frame. So one thing we can do is set a variable, and when `drop` is triggered, return `false` if we're still active.

Comment: i have reasons to belive that this is a jqueryui bug, there is no reason for drop event to be triggered since i haven't mouseup at all!

Comment: @paranic maybe, and can look that up. I feel it's more related to frames that are used for jsfiddle. Does it do this in your live site?

Comment: @paranic take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/18/ with the margin, it only drops when scroll occurs or the mouse is far off from the frame with mousedown.

Comment: @paranic specifically, it looks like Sortable Out is the culprit: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fqkmL07x/37/